# How to mock an object having property as file path to get information in Karma jasmine

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am a fresher and new to Karma and Jasmine. I am writing test cases in Karma Jasmine. Here the problem is how can I mock the SwitchParser object to get the mocked data.
I tried with the following.

```
spyOn(SwitchLogParser.prototype, "parseSwitchLogFile").and.callThrough();

spyOn(SwitchParserFactory.prototype, "getInstance").and.callThrough(); // It gives error as Argument of type '"getInstance"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

The following is the function in Typescript for which I need to write test cases.

```
public static async getParsedSwitchConfig(switchConfig: SwitchInputConfiguration): Promise<SwitchConfigFromLog> {
        let switchConfigFromLog: SwitchConfigFromLog = null;
        try {
            if (switchConfig.$switchLogFilePath) {
                const switchParser: SwitchLogParser  =
                            SwitchParserFactory.getInstance(switchConfig.$switchModel);
                switchConfigFromLog =  await switchParser
                            .parseSwitchLogFile(switchConfig.$switchLogFilePath);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            logger.error("Error while parsing switch log file", error);
        }
        return switchConfigFromLog;
    }
```

Is it possible to mock the Parser object which needs a file path ?
I am able to form the object with some dummy correct data for `SwitchInputConfiguration`.
I want to learn how to mock a an object which requires some actual file to be parsed to get the object.
Please help me.